# MySQL stored procedure returns false

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

After this method is invoked, the stored procedure is called (it puts 1000 new records to db). But bool is false, why?

```
public void loadTestData() throws SQLException {

    CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall("{call loadTestData }");

   boolean bool = cStmt.execute();

   if (bool) System.out.println("test data is loaded");
    else System.out.println("test data is not loaded!");
}
```

---

The Procedure is here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `loadTestData`()
BEGIN

 DECLARE x INT;

 delete from user where id<5000;

 SET x = 0;
  WHILE x <= 100 DO
   insert into user (name, description) VALUES( 
        concat("name", x), 
        concat("description", x)
   );
   SET x = x + 1;
  END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: Can you show `loadTestData` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your procedure's first result is not `ResultSet` the return value is `false`.

**[PreparedStatement.execute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29)**

Comment: make sense. then I would use try-catch to get the feedback - what was the result of the procedure. or add some logic into the procedure, that would return the fact that no need to call the proc, because it was already invoked

Comment: @ses Your procedure doesn't return something (result set) thereby the result will be `false`.